# RaphaelJS random circle inside path always shows on border of path

Tags: javascript, css, path, raphael

I have a US Map generated using RaphaelJS.  Currently I am working specifically on the state path of Florida.  I am trying to generate random circles inside of Florida's state path using RaphaelJS's getBBox() and isPointInsidePath() functions.  When running in the browser it seems to be on the verge of working except that all the points generated seem to be on the State's path border.  When I recreate in JSFiddle the points seem to go inside the state but also outside the state borders always staying within the bounding box.

http://jsfiddle.net/nhm3u60e/

```
var FLPath = "M562.5,325.1l1.7,5.4l2.7,7.2l3.9,7l2.7,4.7l3.6,4.1l3,2.7l1.2,2.1l-0.8,1l-0.6,1l2.1,5.5l2.1,2.1l1.9,3.9l2.7,4.3l3.3,6.1l1,5.6l0.4,8.9l0.4,1.3l-0.2,2.5l-1.8,1l0.2,1.4l-0.4,1.4l0.2,1.8l0.4,1.4l-2,2.4l-2.3,1.1l-2.9,0.1l-1.1,1.2l-1.8,0.7l-1-0.4l-0.8-0.7l-0.2-2.1l-0.6-2.5l-2.5-3.8l-2.7-1.7l-2.9-0.2l-0.6,1l-2.3-3.3l-0.4-2.7l-1.9-3l-1.3-0.8l-1.2,1.6l-1.3-0.2l-1.6-3.7l-2.1-2.9l-2.1-3.9l-1.9-2.3l-2.7-2.7l1.6-1.8l2.4-4.1l-0.1-1.2l-3.3-0.7l-1.2,0.4l0.2,0.4l1.9,0.7l-1.1,3.3l-0.6,0.4l-1.3-3l-1-3.6l-0.2-2l1.1-3.5v-7l-2.3-2.7l-1-2.3l-3.8-1l-1.4-0.4l-1.2-1.9l-2.5-1.2l-0.8-2.5l-2-0.7l-1.8-2.7l-3.1-1.1l-2.1-1.1h-1.9l-3,0.6l-0.1,1.4l0.6,0.7l-0.4,0.8l-2.3-0.1l-2.7,2.7l-2.7,1.4h-2.9l-2.4,1l-0.2-2l-1.2-1.4l-2.1-0.8l-1.2-1.1l-6-2.9l-5.6-1.3l-3.3,0.4l-4.4,0.4l-4.4,1.6l-2.6,0.4l-0.1-5.9l-1.9-1.4l-1.3-1.3l0.2-2.3l7.6-1l18.9-2.1l5-0.4l4,0.2l1.9,2.9l1.1,1.1l6,0.4l8-0.4l15.9-1l4-0.5l3.8,0.1l0.3,2.1l1.6,0.6l0.1-3.4l-1.1-3.1l1-1l4.1,0.4L562.5,325.1z M571.8,423.1l1.8-0.4l1-0.1l1.1-1.7l1.7-1.2l1,0.4l1.3,0.2l0.3,0.8l-2.6,0.9l-3.1,1.1l-1.7,0.9L571.8,423.1z M581.8,419.4l0.9,0.8l2-1.6l3.9-3.1l2.7-2.9l1.9-4.9l0.7-1.3l0.1-2.5l-0.5,0.4l-0.7,2.1l-1.1,3.4l-2.4,3.9l-3.3,3.1l-2.5,1.4L581.8,419.4z";

var random = 5 - 1;

function createVariables(randomNumber, StatePath){
 var statePathNew = paper.path(StatePath);
 var stateBBox = statePathNew.getBBox();
 var accounts = [];
 var i = 0;
 while (i <= randomNumber) {

  var xRandom = Math.floor(Math.random() * (stateBBox.x2 - stateBBox.x + 1)) + stateBBox.x;
  var yRandom = Math.floor(Math.random() * (stateBBox.y2 - stateBBox.y + 1)) + stateBBox.y;

  if(Raphael.isPointInsidePath(StatePath,xRandom,yRandom) === true) {
      accounts[i] = paper.circle(xRandom,yRandom,2).attr({fill:"red"});
      i++;
  }
}
}

createVariables(random, FLPath);
```

My question is how do I generate circles that do not "stick" to the state path/border?